# Is it possible to retrieve a user's relationship status history from Open Graph?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to figure a way to get a user's relationship status history. I know that I can pull a user's current relationship status.

But I want to pull their history in a similar way that Timeline saves a user's work and education history.

I've seen that (depending on how much info the user has given) people's relationships are saved with actual dates such as a person got married on July 22, 2012 or 'in a relationship' October 1, 2011.

So my question is: If a user is in a relationship since October 23, 2012 can I get that info from the API? If this person changes their relationship status would I be able to get that info from the API as well? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know *relationship status history* isn't available from Open Graph.

> relationship_status - User-entered "Relationship Status" profile
>   field. Is either blank or one of the following strings: Single, In a
>   Relationship, In an Open Relationship, Engaged, Married, It's
>   Complicated, Widowed.
>
> significant_other_id - the id of the person the user is in a
>   relationship with. Only shown if both people in the relationship are
>   users of the application making the request.

Have a look here at the table structure: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

**UPDATE:**

You can try and use the [Real-time Updates API](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/01/31/how-to--subscribing-to-data-changes-using-the-real-time-updates-api/) to store the relationship status if it's different from the one you already have.

Comment: Thanks Plurby. What you say makes sense. Could there be a workaround the issue? For example if I wanted to be updated when a relationship status changed and then find out the previous time that status changed as well?

Comment: Look at the update, and please mark as answer if my response was helpful.