# Is there any way to retrive friends anniversary using facebook graph api in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

In my app i am retrieving facebook friend's details like birthday,name,profile pic.But now i want to query for anniversary.I searched a lot in google but couldn't find it.So my question is,is it possible or not.If there is no option in graph api ,is there any other possibilities?
thanks..

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

Check if you can get **relationship_status** , as I can see the same in `fql` and if the returned value comes married then you may look what else is being returned by facebook Graph or fql. I haven't tested it but you may try and let me know too.

Comment: Hi prateek..In relationship_status i am getting only like married or single.But i need the exact date as there in facebook profile..and there is no other field like that.is it possible or not.plz let me know.

Comment: well in this case I would suggest this thread hope it answers your question too http://stackoverflow.com/q/13315100/1503130